# Android ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

This is a repeatation of a post [Recreating off screen pages of ViewPager while changing orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888554/recreating-off-screen-pages-of-viewpager-while-changing-orientation) as i dont get any response and i am in a big trouble.Moreover i am repeating the whole text here.

**Problem:**
From internet i came to know that Android ViewPager needs to set at least 1 offscreen page limit for both side with viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1), in that case when i am watching a page, two more pages in both side of the middle page have already been created. Now the problem is when i am going to Landscape mode and swiping some page and then turn it back to the Portrait mode, only the middle page is being recreated (not the offscreen pages). May be that is why a shadow/marginal portion of the previous page (that was created with landscape margins) is always shown overlapped with the middle page (that is recreated with portrait margins).

Now how to get ride of this problem. I don't want to see this overlapped portion of the previous page. I have attached an image just after going from Landscape mode to Portrait mode.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recreating off screen pages of ViewPager while changing orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888554/recreating-off-screen-pages-of-viewpager-while-changing-orientation) I understand that you need help but don't re ask the exact same question. Edit and improve your first question.

Comment: Ok, i will do that from next time. thanks for your suggestion @Luksprog :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try instantiate adapter with `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupprtFragmentManager()`. I had a similar problem and all I did was it...

Answer (score 0):

Please use getChildFragmentManager() when using viewpager inside Fragments and getSupportManager() when using pager in activities as source for pager adapter